# Create group of non continuous elements in SVG?

Tags: xml, svg

From what I am aware, groups are created using `<g>` tag and each element in the group needs to be written in that. However, I would like to create groups of multiple elements, which may not occur in a consecutive order for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="1920"
   height="1080"
   viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8">
  <g id="layer1">
    <circle pathLength="100" cx="960" cy="1080" r="500" fill-opacity="0" id="circleObjV" stroke-width="40" stroke="#9400D3" stroke-dasharray="50,50" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <circle pathLength="100" cx="960" cy="1080" r="540" fill-opacity="0" id="circleObjI" stroke-width="40" stroke="#4B0082" stroke-dasharray="50,50" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <circle pathLength="100" cx="960" cy="1080" r="580" fill-opacity="0" id="circleObjB" stroke-width="40" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-dasharray="50,50" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <circle pathLength="100" cx="960" cy="1080" r="620" fill-opacity="0" id="circleObjG" stroke-width="40" stroke="#00FF00" stroke-dasharray="50,50" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <circle pathLength="100" cx="960" cy="1080" r="660" fill-opacity="0" id="circleObjY" stroke-width="40" stroke="#FFFF00" stroke-dasharray="50,50" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <circle pathLength="100" cx="960" cy="1080" r="700" fill-opacity="0" id="circleObjO" stroke-width="40" stroke="#FF7F00" stroke-dasharray="50,50" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <circle pathLength="100" cx="960" cy="1080" r="740" fill-opacity="0" id="circleObjR" stroke-width="40" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-dasharray="50,50" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I would like to create a group of `circleObjV` and `circleObjG` while not tampering the order in which they are rendered. Can I in any manner store a reference to an object and reuse it in the group or any other way that would serve the purpose?

Thanks

Comment: SVG has layers.  You are showing layer 1.  The layers are overlays that allow you to enable any combinations of layers.  So you could have a map and display the roads and street names or disable the roads and street names.

Comment: Document order is rendering order. You can't separate the two concepts (normally).

Comment: Why use a group at all?